# installing uwsgi on cygwin

Tags: cygwin, uwsgi

Have anyone managed to install uwsgi on cygwin (python 2.7) ?

```
{ uwsgi-2.0.11.2 }  » python setup.py install
running install
using profile: buildconf/default.ini
detected include path: ['/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include', '/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include-fixed', '/usr/include', '/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../include/w32api']
Patching "bin_name" to properly install_scripts dir
detected CPU cores: 1
configured CFLAGS: -O2 -I. -Wall -Werror -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -fno-strict-aliasing -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -DUWSGI_HAS_IFADDRS -DUWSGI_ZLIB -DUWSGI_LOCK_USE_WINDOWS_MUTEX -DUWSGI_EVENT_USE_POLL -DUWSGI_EVENT_TIMER_USE_NONE -DUWSGI_EVENT_FILEMONITOR_USE_NONE -DUWSGI_UUID -DUWSGI_VERSION="\"2.0.11.2\"" -DUWSGI_VERSION_BASE="2" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MAJOR="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MINOR="11" -DUWSGI_VERSION_REVISION="2" -DUWSGI_VERSION_CUSTOM="\"\"" -DUWSGI_YAML -DUWSGI_SSL -DUWSGI_PLUGIN_DIR="\".\"" -DUWSGI_DECLARE_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="UDEP(python);UDEP(gevent);UDEP(ping);UDEP(cache);UDEP(nagios);UDEP(rrdtool);UDEP(carbon);UDEP(rpc);UDEP(corerouter);UDEP(fastrouter);UDEP(http);UDEP(signal);UDEP(syslog);UDEP(rsyslog);UDEP(logsocket);UDEP(router_uwsgi);UDEP(router_redirect);UDEP(router_basicauth);UDEP(zergpool);UDEP(redislog);UDEP(mongodblog);UDEP(router_rewrite);UDEP(router_http);UDEP(logfile);UDEP(router_cache);UDEP(rawrouter);UDEP(router_static);UDEP(sslrouter);UDEP(spooler);UDEP(cheaper_busyness);UDEP(symcall);UDEP(transformation_tofile);UDEP(transformation_gzip);UDEP(transformation_chunked);UDEP(transformation_offload);UDEP(router_memcached);UDEP(router_redis);UDEP(router_hash);UDEP(router_expires);UDEP(router_metrics);UDEP(transformation_template);UDEP(stats_pusher_socket);" -DUWSGI_LOAD_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="ULEP(python);ULEP(gevent);ULEP(ping);ULEP(cache);ULEP(nagios);ULEP(rrdtool);ULEP(carbon);ULEP(rpc);ULEP(corerouter);ULEP(fastrouter);ULEP(http);ULEP(signal);ULEP(syslog);ULEP(rsyslog);ULEP(logsocket);ULEP(router_uwsgi);ULEP(router_redirect);ULEP(router_basicauth);ULEP(zergpool);ULEP(redislog);ULEP(mongodblog);ULEP(router_rewrite);ULEP(router_http);ULEP(logfile);ULEP(router_cache);ULEP(rawrouter);ULEP(router_static);ULEP(sslrouter);ULEP(spooler);ULEP(cheaper_busyness);ULEP(symcall);ULEP(transformation_tofile);ULEP(transformation_gzip);ULEP(transformation_chunked);ULEP(transformation_offload);ULEP(router_memcached);ULEP(router_redis);ULEP(router_hash);ULEP(router_expires);ULEP(router_metrics);ULEP(transformation_template);ULEP(stats_pusher_socket);"
*** uWSGI compiling server core ***
[gcc] core/utils.o
core/utils.c: In function ‘uwsgi_as_root’:
core/utils.c:848:4: error: implicit declaration of function ‘initgroups’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
    if (initgroups(uidname, uwsgi.gid)) {
    ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

I have got make, automake , gcc (4.9.2) . Do I need anything else ?

Comment: Hi, did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same issue under Windows 7, `gcc (GCC) 4.9.3` and `GNU Make 4.1`. There actually 3 issues that needed to be resolved. The first being to disable the GCC warnings by removing the `-Wall` flag. The second is to remove the GCC `-rdynamic` linker option when using Cygwin. The last issue is that you need to install `libcrypt-devel` using Cygwin's setup installer.

Here is is what my `git diff uwsgiconfig.py` looks like. Note that I cloned the `master` branch from [GitHub](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi).

```
diff --git a/uwsgiconfig.py b/uwsgiconfig.py
index 3279777..cca00cf 100644
--- a/uwsgiconfig.py
+++ b/uwsgiconfig.py
@@ -1,5 +1,6 @@
 # uWSGI build system

+
 uwsgi_version = '2.1-dev'

 import os
@@ -621,7 +622,7 @@ class uConf(object):
         self.cflags = [
             '-O2',
             '-I.',
-            '-Wall',
+            # '-Wall',
             '-Werror',
             '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE',
             '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64'
@@ -842,6 +843,9 @@ class uConf(object):
             if GCC in ('clang',):
                 self.libs.remove('-rdynamic')

+        if uwsgi_os.startswith('CYGWIN'):
+            self.libs.remove('-rdynamic')
+
         # compile extras
         extras = self.get('extras', None)
         if extras:
```

Then a simple `make` within the cloned uwsgi directory should build everything.

I tested it by creating a file called `app.py` with the following -

```
def application(env, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('content-type', 'text/html')])

    return [b'asdasdasd']
```

Then run the server with -

```
./uwsgi --http :9090 --wsgi-file app.py
```

Everything worked fine when I accessed http://localhost:9090/.

Answer (score 0):

I am successed with only using [latest uwsgi](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Changelog-2.0.18.html) and [latest Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). **The core is step 2**

step:

1. dowload [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe)
2. install： *when you install, you must choose to install pip and python (my is python2.7.16) ==> this is python for Cygwin, not the python installed on Windows and use in Cygwin shell*([REF TO](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/520#issuecomment-34948507))
3. dowload [uwsgi](https://projects.unbit.it/downloads/uwsgi-2.0.18.tar.gz)
4. install `cd {YOUR uwsgi}; python2.7.exe setup install`(`python2.7.exe` is that created by python for Cygwin that you choose in step2, your may diff, find at `/bin/pythonX.x.exe`, add it to `PATH` just like in linux(`/etc/profile` or `~/.bash_profile`))
5. if error in step 4 occurred, like 'xxx/ld not found -lintl`, go to step2 find it(usually xxx-devel) and install
6. use `uwsig`: `python and most cmd in Cygwin` can only run at Cygwin console(else access denial), but you can use uwsgi, add it to your `WINDOWS PATH`, and install package like django in at Cygwin console.