# Can't install uwsgi on cygwin

Tags: python-3.x, windows, cygwin

My main OS is windows 10 but I am using cygwin as a terminal. While installing uwsgi through `pip3 install uwsgi` command , it fails with an error message " AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'uname'"

Comment: You have an *os.py* (or *os.pyc*, ...) somewhere in your *PYTHONPATH* (possibly in current directory?). Or you're running a *Win* (**not** *Cygwin*) installed *Python* (what does `python -c "import sys; print(sys.platform)"`output?). Or the *Python* installation is corrupt.

Comment: Cygwin is not a terminal. It is a Unix-like enviroment. For me uwsgi installation works. Have you installed the `python3-devel` package ?

Comment: see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55714871/6493535)

Answer (score 3):

uWSGI needs a c compiler to build and the os.uname to use platform.uname needs to be updated in the uwsgiconfig.py file.

Here is how to fix for windows 10:

1. cd to uwsgi install directory and open uwsgiconfig.py
2. replace os.uname with platform.uname for the following lines of code:

   uwsgi_os = **os.uname**()[0]
   uwsgi_os_k = re.split('[-+_]', **os.uname**()[2])[0]
   uwsgi_os_v = **os.uname**()[3]
   uwsgi_cpu = **os.uname**()[4]

to this:

```
uwsgi_os = **platform.uname**()[0]
uwsgi_os_k = re.split('[-+_]', **platform.uname**()[2])[0]
uwsgi_os_v = **platform.uname**()[3]
uwsgi_cpu = **platform.uname**()[4]
```

3. Install the following packages with cygwin to make sure you have python3 and gcc available for cygwin terminal and not just python installed on windows. This is a separate python install than for windows itself.

   - Open windows cmd terminal
   - cd to cygwin64 (or your install dir)
   - run this command:
     setup-x86_64.exe -q -P wget -P gcc-g++ -P gcc-core -P gcc-g++ -P libcrypt-devel -P libintl-devel -P python3 -P python3-devel
   - This command should install the following packages for Cygwin64:
     gcc-core
     gcc-g++
     libcrypt-devel
     libintl-devel
     python3
     python3-devel

     4. In Cygwin terminal window
   - cd to uwsgi directory
   - type and run command 'python3 setup.py install'
   - wait for this to finish and do a happy dance.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am getting below error .`core/event.c: In function ‘event_queue_read’:
core/event.c:1416:9: error: ‘UWSGI_EVENT_IN’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘UWSGI_VERSION’?
  return UWSGI_EVENT_IN;`

Comment: @Gopi did you fix it?

Answer (score 2):

If you get:

`core/event.c: In function ‘event_queue_read’: core/event.c:1416:9: error: ‘UWSGI_EVENT_IN’ undeclared`

probably you don't start setup install with cygwin python

Answer (score 0):

Code need to be changed a bit to:

```
import platform
uwsgi_os = platform.uname()[0]
uwsgi_os_k = re.split('[-+_]', platform.uname()[2])[0]
uwsgi_os_v = platform.uname()[3]
uwsgi_cpu = platform.uname()[4]
```