# Cant install uwsgi in windows10 using cygwin

Tags: python-3.x, windows, cygwin, uwsgi

I tried installing uwsgi using cygwin in windows10 by following the below steps which i found in another question of stackoverflow. 
[Can't install uwsgi on cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54200746/cant-install-uwsgi-on-cygwin)

uwsgi version : 2.0.18

I am getting the below error.

```
$ python setup.py install
using profile: buildconf/default.ini
detected include path: ['/usr/include', '/usr/local/include']
running install
core/event.c: In function ‘event_queue_read’:
core/event.c:1420:9: error: ‘UWSGI_EVENT_IN’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘UWSGI_VERSION’?
  return UWSGI_EVENT_IN;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         UWSGI_VERSION
core/event.c:1420:9: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
core/event.c: In function ‘event_queue_write’:
core/event.c:1424:9: error: ‘UWSGI_EVENT_OUT’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘UWSGI_END_CODE’?
  return UWSGI_EVENT_OUT;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         UWSGI_END_CODE
core/event.c: In function ‘event_queue_read’:
core/event.c:1421:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
 }
 ^
core/event.c: In function ‘event_queue_write’:
core/event.c:1425:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
 }
 ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Please help me

Comment: Did you fix it?